# Find when a subview is touched when it is animating in iphone?

Tags: iphone, animation, subview, uitouch, addsubview

I added a subview to the view. I am finding it when touched, when it is animating touch event is finding the subview..
Here is the code...

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        if ([touch self]) {
            NSLog(@"View Touched");
        }
        if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[Baloon class]]) {
            NSLog(@"Baloon Touched");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should implement the "touchesBegan" Method in your Baloon Class and in the "touchesMove" Method set the new Position to the Baloon!

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


  NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
  switch ([allTouches count]) {
    case 1: {
      UITouch *touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

      [self setCenter:[touch locationInView:self.superview]];
    }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```